Problem to many redirect Kubernetes + ingress + nginx
I have a problem with too many redirects in nginx.
Here is my yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-mizuconecta
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /mnt/data/mizuconecta
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: standard

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc-mizuconecta
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: standard

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: php-fpm-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: php-fpm
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: php-fpm
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: php-fpm
        image: php:fpm-alpine
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/www/html
          name: php-storage
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "2Gi"
            cpu: "2"
          requests:
            memory: "2Gi"
            cpu: "1"
        env:
        - name: PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT
          value: "2G"
        - name: PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME
          value: "900"
        - name: PHP_MAX_INPUT_TIME
          value: "900"
        - name: PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE
          value: "200M"
        - name: PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE
          value: "200M"
        - name: PHP_MAX_FILE_UPLOADS
          value: "20"
        - name: PHP_OPCACHE_MEMORY_CONSUMPTION
          value: "128"
      volumes:
      - name: php-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: pvc-mizuconecta

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: php-fpm-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: php-fpm
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000
      name: php

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "200m"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "900"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "900"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false" # Desativar redirecionamento forçado
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false" # Desativar redirecionamento SSL
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - mizuconecta.mizu.com.br
    secretName: tls-mizu
  rules:
  - host: mizuconecta.mizu.com.br
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-service
            port:
              number: 80


---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      name: https
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      name: http

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 443
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/www/html/
          name: nginx-storage
        - mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
          name: nginx-config
        - mountPath: /etc/nginx/ssl
          name: nginx-ssl
      volumes:
      - name: nginx-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: pvc-mizuconecta
      - name: nginx-config
        configMap:
          name: nginx-config
      - name: nginx-ssl
        secret:
          secretName: tls-mizu

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-config
data:
  default.conf: |
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name dominio.com
        
        location / {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri; # Redirecionar HTTP para HTTPS
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name dominio.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/tls.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/tls.key;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html;

        keepalive_timeout 900;
        client_header_timeout 900;
        client_body_timeout 900;
        reset_timedout_connection on;
        send_timeout 900;
        fastcgi_buffers 8 128k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        client_max_body_size 200m;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass php-fpm-service:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }
    }



here logs
root@srv-dcay01:/home/triplex/axcel/camunda/nginx/novo# kubectl logs -l app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx -n ingress-nginx
W0605 13:40:45.294575       1 client_config.go:618] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
{"err":"secrets "ingress-nginx-admission" not found","level":"info","msg":"no secret found","source":"k8s/k8s.go:229","time":"2024-06-05T13:40:45Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"creating new secret","source":"cmd/create.go:28","time":"2024-06-05T13:40:45Z"}
W0605 13:40:47.003989       1 client_config.go:618] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
{"level":"info","msg":"patching webhook configurations 'ingress-nginx-admission' mutating=false, validating=true, failurePolicy=Fail","source":"k8s/k8s.go:118","time":"2024-06-05T13:40:47Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Patched hook(s)","source":"k8s/k8s.go:138","time":"2024-06-05T13:40:47Z"}
177.91.216.253 - - [05/Jun/2024:17:31:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0" 25 0.001 [default-nginx-service-80] [] 10.244.0.72:80 169 0.000 301 6da273aec3981569189b28d0c6fcdca1
177.91.216.253 - - [05/Jun/2024:17:31:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0" 25 0.000 [default-nginx-service-80] [] 10.244.0.73:80 169 0.001 301 d2ea029c296d20e14c8c0e0d33df38bd
177.91.216.253 - - [05/Jun/2024:17:31:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0" 25 0.001 [default-nginx-service-80] [] 10.244.0.72:80 169 0.000 301 a710973ce9605404331cd90809e8ac8e
177.91.216.253 - - [05/Jun/2024:17:31:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0" 25 0.001 [default-nginx-service-80] [] 10.244.0.73:80 169 0.000 301 d93c46f009661489e90fa49dd725c4b5
177.91.216.253 - - [05/Jun/2024:17:31:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0" 25 0.000 [default-nginx-service-80] [] 10.244.0.72:80 169 0.001 301 ad478864c45f1ce80ef1ccbdb2488bac
177.91.216.253 - - [05/Jun/2024:17:31:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0" 25 0.000 [default-nginx-service-80] [] 10.244.0.73:80 169 0.001 301 679677a9b59e8af63f849dad3c9e30c8
177.91.216.253 - - [05/Jun/2024:17:31:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0" 25 0.001 [default-nginx-service-80] [] 10.244.0.72:80 169 0.000 301 497c168e753c701b3b05eabba9d98840
177.91.216.253 - - [05/Jun/2024:17:31:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0" 25 0.001 [default-nginx-service-80] [] 10.244.0.73:80 169 0.000 301 d37e2cf2669d0d5abe2aeed5dc022547
177.91.216.253 - - [05/Jun/2024:17:31:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0" 25 0.001 [default-nginx-service-80] [] 10.244.0.72:80 169 0.000 301 062146bc5b1af98799122eb99712837c
177.91.216.253 - - [05/Jun/2024:17:31:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0" 25 0.001 [default-nginx-service-80] [] 10.244.0.73:80 169 0.000 301 627f7c25260b729b52fa24d726fac688
root@srv-dcay01:/home/triplex/axcel/camunda/nginx/novo# ^C
I've already tried changing the configmap and ingress settings but either it shows that I'm using http over https or it gives too many redirects

    apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-mizuconecta
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /mnt/data/mizuconecta
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: standard

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc-mizuconecta
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: standard

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx
data:
  nginx.conf: |
    server {
      listen 80;
      listen [::]:80;
      listen 443 ssl;
      listen [::]:443 ssl;

      ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/tls.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/tls.key;


        keepalive_timeout 900;
        client_header_timeout 900;
        client_body_timeout 900;
        reset_timedout_connection on;
        send_timeout 900;
        fastcgi_buffers 8 128k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        client_max_body_size 200m;

      access_log off;
      root /var/www/html;
      index index.php;
      server_name mizuconecta.mizu.com.br;
      server_tokens off;
      location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
      }
      location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php-app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
      }
    }

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - mizuconecta.mizu.com.br
    secretName: tls-mizu
  rules:
  - host: mizuconecta.mizu.com.br
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-service
            port:
              number: 80

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
    layer: frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
            - containerPort: 443
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/www/html/
              name: contents
            - name: nginx-config
              mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
              subPath: nginx.conf
            - name: tls-secret
              mountPath: /etc/nginx/ssl
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: contents
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvc-mizuconecta
        - name: nginx-config
          configMap:
            name: nginx
        - name: tls-secret
          secret:
            secretName: tls-mizu

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      name: http
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      name: https

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: php-app
  labels:
    app: php-app
    layer: backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: php-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: php-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: php-app
          image: php:fpm-alpine
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9000
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/www/html/
              name: contents
          env:
            - name: PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT
              value: "2G"
            - name: PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME
              value: "900"
            - name: PHP_MAX_INPUT_TIME
              value: "900"
            - name: PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE
              value: "200M"
            - name: PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE
              value: "200M"
            - name: PHP_MAX_FILE_UPLOADS
              value: "20"
            - name: PHP_OPCACHE_MEMORY_CONSUMPTION
              value: "128"
      volumes:
        - name: contents
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvc-mizuconecta

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: php-app
  labels:
    app: php-app
    layer: backend
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: php-app
  ports:
    - port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000
      name: php

this charts works

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
